# Metric spaces - continuity - open/closed.

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $f:(M_1,d_1)\to (M_2,d_2)$ be a mapping between two metric spaces.
>
> a)Let $A\subseteq M_1$ be open and $B\subseteq M_1$ closed. Show through the use of counterexamples that in general $f(A)$ is not open and $f(B)$ is not closed in $M_2$.
>
> b) Show that **f** is continuous when the pre-images of closed sets in **f** are closed again.

Just started learning about metric spaces in general and this one piqued my interest in the textbook.

Here's what I thought:

a) Although I'm allowed to use counterexamples I don't know how to start. I was thinking that I need to find a set in $M_1$ whose ball is not open in $M_2$, right? And similarly for **B**, that the corresponding set in $M_2$ is not closed, meaning that the complement is not open?

But how can I show that? I mean, I have no explicit norm given to set up the balls. Any ideas?

b) We weren't at the chapter of continuity in metric spaces so I tried reading about it somewhere. It seems kind of similar to proving continuity in $\mathbb{R}$? But again, I don't know how to approach this without a norm. According to my textbook I'm supposed to show that

$d_2(f(x),f(x_0))<\epsilon$ if $d_1(x,x_0)<\delta$, correct?

But I seriously don't know how to use that to deal with b), especially since they require pre-images of **f**.

Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: My approach for a): 
$$
d(x,y) :=  \begin{cases}0, &x = y\\1, & x\neq y\end{cases}
$$

$B_r(x)=\{y\in \mathbb{R}|d(x,y)<r\}$  $x\in \mathbb{R},~r>0$

$B_{1/2}(0)=\{0\}$ is open for $x=y$.

For $d_2:|x-y|$

No finite number of open intervals so that the intersection is zero.

$\rightarrow f(B_{1/2}(0))$ is not open.

*For the closed case:*

You said I should take the complement of all the balls used for the open case, meaning:

$B_r(x)=\{y\in \mathbb{R}|d_1(x,y)>r\}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R},r>0$.

$\rightarrow$ $B_{1/2}^{d_1}(0)={1}$ is closed in $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$?

So for $d_2(x,y):=|x-y|$ and $f:(\mathbb{R},d_1)\to (\mathbb{R},d_2),x\mapsto x$. 
So similarly it should be $f(B_{1/2}^{d_1}(0))=\{1\}$, and $\{1\}$ is not closed because for all $r>0:B_r^{d_2}(0)={0}$ and not $\{1\}$, right?

Comment: writing $B_r(x)=\{y\in\mathbb R|d_1(x,y)>r\}$ is misleading. IMHO usually one expects $B_r(x)$ to be the ball around $x$, not its complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** In such exercises, you are allowed to use any metric and mapping you wish to. A nice one for counterexamples is
$$
d(x,y) :=  \begin{cases}0, &x = y\\1, & x\neq y\end{cases}
$$
What is the ball $B_r(x)=\{y\in\mathbb R\mid d(x,y)<r\}$ around $x\in\mathbb R, r>0$ with this metric? Can you find a mapping that maps it to a non-open set? (Remember that $d_1$ and $d_2$ may be different.)

(*Side Remark*: A metric space is by no means normed, for example if it has the metric $d$ given above.)

**b)** Usually *continuous* is defined as "the preimages of open sets are open". To prove your statement, use that open sets are the complements of closed ones:

Let $f:S\to T$ be a function where preimages of closed sets are closed. Let $A\in T$ be open, $B:=T\setminus A$. Hence B is closed, and by assumption $\tilde B=f^{-1}(B)$ is closed to. Use that to show that $\tilde A=f^{-1}(A)$ is open, which concludes your proof.

---

#### My suggestions for your approach above

$$
d_1(x,y) :=  \begin{cases}0, &x = y\\1, & x\neq y\end{cases}
$$

Hence in $(\mathbb R, d_1)$ the open balls are $B_r(x)=\{y\in \mathbb{R}|d_1(x,y)<r\}$  for $x\in \mathbb{R},~r>0$

$\Rightarrow A:=B^{d_1}_{1/2}(0)=\{0\}$ is open in $(\mathbb R, d_1)$.

Let $d_2(x,y):=|x-y|$ and $f:(\mathbb R,d_1)\to(\mathbb R,d_2), x\mapsto x$

Thus $f(A)=\{0\}$, but $\{0\}$ is not open in $(\mathbb R, d_2)$ since $\not\exists r>0:B_r^{d_2}(0) = \{0\}$

*For the closed set case, it suffices to take the complements of all the balls above:*

Let $B := A^C = \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$. $B$ is closed in $(\mathbb R, d_1)$ as complement of the open set $A$.

$\Rightarrow f(B) = B$ is not closed in $(\mathbb R, d_2)$ since its complement $A$ is not open (see above).

Comment: About a): So, if I were to pick $r=0.5$ the ball would be open for $x=y$, but otherwise the points would jump out of the ball? About b): I don't know how to show continuity yet. I just don't know how to start.

Comment: @Fabian: a) Exactly, $B_{1/2}(0) = \{0\}$ with the $d$ above. Now think about a metric space where that set is not open, and use the identity map. b) I'll edit my answer

Comment: How can I use an identity map on metrics? Is it similar to functions?

Comment: @Fabian: If $M_1=M_2=\mathbb R$, $d_1=d$ (from above) and $d_2$ any metric on $\mathbb R$, you can use the identity $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. The metrics have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Alright, I tried the same approach as you showed in b) with the mappings. And for $d_2$ I chose $|x-y|$. So, I try to get $f(B_{1/2}(0))$, right? So how can I show that $B_{1/2}'$ is also not open like $B_{1/2}(0)$?

Comment: With the metric induced by the absolute value (as norm), the open sets are exactly the unions of open intervals. Hence $f(B_{1/2}(0))=\{0\}$ is not open.

Comment: Aren't the unions of open intervals closed sets? Like for example $[-\infty,0)\cap (1,\infty]=[0,1]$?

Comment: $(-\infty,0)\cap (1,\infty) = \emptyset$ which is open (and closed, too). And by the way, that is an intersection. The union $(-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)$ is open, since $\mathbb R\setminus (-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)=[0,1]$ is closed. You can read the definition of a topological space on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Open_sets_definition

Comment: Oh, stupid me. But why would $f(B_{1/2}(0))={0}$ not be open?

Comment: in the metric induced by the absolute value $\lvert\cdot\rvert$, single points like $\{0\}$ are not open. (There is no finite number of open intervals such that their intersection is a single point).

Comment: Could you look at what I wrote down for a) in the original post? I'm still not sure how to write down what is needed to be shown in an appropriate mathematical manner.

Comment: I don't get what you want with the part starting from $r>2$. For the rest I have added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: The r>2 is for the $B\subseteq M_1$ which is closed. I tried showing that the mapping of that $B$ is not closed in $M_2$.

Comment: If you take $r\ge 1$, then $B_r^{d_1}(0)=\mathbb R$ which is open and closed in both topologies. See my remark in the answer for the closed set case.

Comment: Okay, I took the complements of all the balls and adjusted it for the closed case in my post, but is that enough?

Comment: I extended my answer. Make yourself clear what the metric $d_1$ means, it has nothing to do with the intuitive notion of a metric.